# Shutdown EC2 Instance if idle right before another billable hour

Tags: timer, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

At unpredictable times (user request) I need to run a memory-intensive job. For this I get a spot or on-demand instance and mark it with a tag as `non_idle`. When the job is done (which may take hours), I give it the tag `idle`. Due to the hourly billing model of AWS, I want to keep that instance alive until another billable hour is incurred in case another job comes in. If a job comes in, the instance should be reused and marked it as `non_idle`. If no job comes in during that time, the instance should terminate.

Does AWS offer a ready solution for this? As far as I know, CloudWatch can't set alarms that should run at a specific time, never mind using the CPUUtilization or the instance's tags. Otherwise, perhaps I could simply set up for every created instance a java timer or scala actor that runs every hour after the instance is created and check for the tag `idle`.

Comment: can't scheduled lambda functions be useful here? https://medium.com/geekculture/terraform-setup-for-scheduled-lambda-functions-f01931040007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no readily available AWS solution for this fine grained optimization, but you can use the existing building blocks to build you own based on the launch time of the current instance indeed (see Dmitriy Samovskiy's smart solution for deducing [How Long Ago Was This EC2 Instance Started?](http://www.somic.org/2009/06/04/how-long-ago-was-this-ec2-instance-started/)).

### Playing 'Chicken'

Shlomo Swidler has explored this optimization in his article [Play “Chicken” with Spot Instances](http://shlomoswidler.com/2011/02/play-chicken-with-spot-instances.html), albeit with a slightly different motivation in the context of [Amazon EC2 Spot Instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/):

> AWS Spot Instances have an interesting economic characteristic that
>   make it possible to game the system a little. Like all EC2 instances,
>   when you initiate termination of a Spot Instance then you incur a
>   charge for the entire hour, even if you’ve used less than a full hour.
>   But, when AWS terminates the instance due to the spot price exceeding
>   the bid price, you do not pay for the current hour.

The mechanics are the same of course, so you might be able to simply reuse the script he assembled, i.e. execute this script instead of or in addition to tagging the instance as `idle`:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
t=/tmp/ec2.running.seconds.$$
if wget -q -O $t http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4 ; then
    # add 60 seconds artificially as a safety margin
    let runningSecs=$(( `date +%s` - `date -r $t +%s` ))+60
    rm -f $t
    let runningSecsThisHour=$runningSecs%3600
    let runningMinsThisHour=$runningSecsThisHour/60
    let leftMins=60-$runningMinsThisHour
    # start shutdown one minute earlier than actually required
    let shutdownDelayMins=$leftMins-1
    if [[ $shutdownDelayMins > 1 && $shutdownDelayMins < 60 ]]; then
        echo "Shutting down in $shutdownDelayMins mins."
        # TODO: Notify off-instance listener that the game of chicken has begun
        sudo shutdown -h +$shutdownDelayMins
    else
        echo "Shutting down now."
        sudo shutdown -h now
    fi
    exit 0
fi
echo "Failed to determine remaining minutes in this billable hour. Terminating now."
sudo shutdown -h now
exit 1
```

Once *a job comes in* you could then cancel the scheduled termination instead of or in addition to tagging the instance with `non_idle` as follows:

```sh
sudo shutdown -c
```

This is also the the 'red button' emergency command during testing/operation, see e.g. Shlomo's warning:

> Make sure you really understand what this script does before you use
>   it. If you mistakenly schedule an instance to be shut down you can
>   cancel it with this command, run on the instance: sudo shutdown -c

### Adding CloudWatch to the game

You could take Shlomo's self contained approach even further by integrating with [Amazon CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/), which recently added an option to [Use Amazon CloudWatch to Detect and Shut Down Unused Amazon EC2 Instances](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/01/08/use-amazon-cloudwatch-to-detect-and-shut-down-unused-amazon-ec2-instances/), see the introductory blog post [Amazon CloudWatch - Alarm Actions](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/01/amazon-cloudwatch-alarm-actions.html) for details:

> Today we are giving you the ability to **stop** or terminate **your EC2
>   instances when a CloudWatch alarm is triggered**. You can use this as a
>   failsafe (detect an abnormal condition and then act) or as part of
>   your application's processing logic (await an expected condition and
>   then act). *[emphasis mine]*

Your use case is listed in section *Application Integration* specifically:

> You can also create CloudWatch alarms based on [Custom Metrics](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/05/amazon-cloudwatch-user-defined-metrics.html) that you
>   observe on an instance-by-instance basis. You could, for example,
>   measure calls to your own web service APIs, page requests, or message
>   postings per minute, and respond as desired.

So you could leverage this new functionality by [Publishing Custom Metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/publishingMetrics.html) to CloudWatch to indicate whether an instance should terminate (is `idle`) based on and Dmitriy's launch time detection and reset the metric again once *a job comes in* and an instance should keep running (is `non_idle`) - like so EC2 would take care of the termination, 2 out of 3 automation steps would have been moved from the instance into the operations environment and management and visibility of the automation process improved accordingly.

Comment: I like a lot the idea of "Play Chicken" and having a bidding strategy that considers the expected probability that amazon will terminate your instance for you. More info for a spot bidding strategy: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/wwwb/cgi-bin/tr-get.cgi/2011/CS/CS-2011-09.pdf and http://cloudexchange.org/

Comment: @jmcejuela - That would be a pretty advanced optimization indeed - if you are aiming that high you probably want to base your solution on more reliable and externally visible automation processes as well, so I've added a suggestion how to add CloudWatch instrumentation to the automation process.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about custom metrics. However, for my use case they are overkill since they charge alarms & metrics per instance and per month. I may run hundreds or thousands of different instances so the cloudwatch costs may end up being higher than those for the instances themselves. I will use a "Play Chicken"-like solution instead. -- Thanks a lot for your help and detailed answer!

Comment: Warning: This method might work but it's not reliable for any case.
It is probably good for a 1 hour meassurement but it's not reliable as those meta data files can be RE-CREATED by AWS and then the file date is wrong.
So whenever that happens your date is wrong.
It's a rare event (like once in a few months) but happened to me.