# AWS run instance for exact amount of full billing cycles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to optimize cost for my project for some valid reasons we're running it on very expensive instances.

To the best of my knowledge Amazon charges by hours. For instance, if I'm running my EC2 instance for 1 hour and 4 minutes I'll be charged 2 hours.

What would be the best way to shut down instance closest to the next billing cycle, but not exceeding current one?

I was trying to do this based on uptime, but there is some difference between aws billing and uptime value.

I'm looking to use watchdog sitting on the instance itself. So I can pass parameters during provision and it will shut down itself say after 2 full billing cycles.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899544/shutdown-ec2-instance-if-idle-right-before-another-billable-hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the time that Amazon starts billing from the EC2 instance (assumes you have jq installed)

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document/ | jq .pendingTime
```

and you could run a shell script once a minute to shut down after, say 58 minutes.

But this is a pain.  If your processing is able to handle interruptions of an instance running then you should look at using [spot instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/) perhaps with a [fixed duration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#fixed-duration-spot-instances).  This allows you to run at a reduced price for a known period of time without any additional costs because of running over.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this command. This is exactly what I was looking for. Spot instance is not an option for us because of business nuances.

Comment: When AWS counts that instance is off. Based on api terminate instance command, or when OS completely shut down?

Comment: I wouldn't trust that it is the instant you issue the command - I'd give it at least 1 minute to shutdown.  A terminate in the console takes at least 30 seconds until I see the terminated state - shutdown is similar.

Answer (score 0):

If your workload is complete before the full hour, stop/terminate your instance right away when the work is complete. No need to keep the instance idle for the remainder of the hour.

The only time this may not be efficient is if you may have more work coming in before the full hour, and then you want to keep it running to process that new work. But that will only be the case if work is sporadic. And if it is sporadic, then it just may be better to keep it running.

Comment: The main thing is that it is an event driven system with very aggressive restrictions from the business side. It is running by schedule right now, what I'm trying to do is to optimize AWS cost.